# Hypothesis Testing: Probability $\beta$ of Type II Error in Proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, type-i-and-ii-errors

$\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\!\left(#1\right)}$
**Background Question:** A manufacturer claimed that at least $20\%$ of the public
preferred his product. A sample of $100$ persons is taken to check his claim.
With $\alpha=0.05,$ how small would the sample percentage have to be before
the claim could legitimately be refuted? (Notice that this would involve a
one-tailed test of the hypothesis.) Note: This is Exercise 10.18 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Sheaffer.

**Answer to Background Question:** We would have $H_0: p=0.2, H_a: p<0.2.$ At the $\alpha=0.05$ level, the
rejection region would be $z<-1.645.$ This would require:
\begin{align*}
z&<-1.645\\
\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{\dfrac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}}&<-1.645\\
\hat{p}-p_0&<-1.645\sqrt{\dfrac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}\\
\hat{p}&<p_0-1.645\sqrt{\dfrac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n}}\\
\hat{p}&<0.2-1.645\sqrt{\dfrac{0.2(0.8)}{100}}\\
\hat{p}&<0.1342.
\end{align*}

**Problem Statement:** Refer to the **Background Question**. Calculate the value of $\beta$ for the alternative $p_a=0.15.$ Note: This is Exercise 10.27 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th. Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Sheaffer.

**My Work So Far:** In the background question, we had $p_0=0.2,\; n=100.$ We found that the rejection
region was $z<-2.575,$ corresponding to $\hat{p}<0.097.$ We have that
\begin{align*}
\beta
&=P\szdp{\frac{\hat{p}-p_a}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}\ge 
         \frac{p_0-p_a}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}}\\
&=P(z\ge 1.25)\\
&=0.1056.
\end{align*}

**My Question:** The book does not have an example of calculating $\beta$ for a proportion, so I'm trying to go by analogy, and it's not working. The book's answer is $0.67.$ Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you obtain the criterion $Z \lt -2.575$ for the rejection region??

Comment: @whuber: For $\alpha=0.05,$ a standard normal distribution in a one-sided test would have $1.645,$ not $2.575.$ Must have looked that up in the table wrong. Let's see: fixing that error in the background question would mean we would have to have $\hat{p}<0.1342.$ However, that doesn't affect the key calculation in the main problem, at least not the way I've written it.

Comment: @Dave The required power is not specified. I have copied down both problem statements word-for-word.

Comment: The critical region is unchanged, so it was crucial first to get it right.  Now, given that the true probability is $0.15,$ what is the chance the test statistic will lie in that critical region?

Comment: @whuber I think I'm confused about terminology. What do you mean by "true probability"? We are supposed to calculate the probability that the test statistic will not lie in the rejection region, correct?

Comment: You can't compute any probabilities until you make a specific assumption about what the underlying distribution is.  That's what $\beta$ corresponds to.  The power is a function of the probability distribution.  Abstractly, the null hypothesis $H_0$ determines the distribution of a sample statistic $t.$  Given $\alpha,$ this determines a critical region $\mathcal{R}_\alpha.$ The alternate hypothesis $H_A$ is a set of distributions.  The *power* is a function of $H_A:$ its value at any distribution $F\in H_A$ is the chance $t(X)\in\mathcal{R}_\alpha$ when $X$ is sampled from $F.$

Comment: I think I was plugging numbers in wrong, even before I corrected the $0.097$ to $0.1342.$ It should be $$\beta
=P\!\left(\frac{\hat{p}-p_a}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}\ge 
        \frac{0.1342-0.15}{\sqrt{0.2(0.8)/100}}\right)=0.6536.$$

Comment: @AdrianKeister I see that you've edited the title to include "(Solved)." The way to show that a question is solved on SE is to accept an answer. If an existing answer does not solve your problem, then you can write your own and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was plugging numbers in wrong, even before I corrected the $0.097$ to $0.1342.$ It should be
\begin{align*}
\beta
&=P\!\left(\frac{\hat{p}-p_a}{\sqrt{p_a(1-p_a)/n}}\ge 
         \frac{0.1342-0.15}{\sqrt{0.15(0.85)/100}}\right)\\
&=P(z\ge -0.448)\\
&=0.67
\end{align*}